# Why aren't these basic html/css codes working with this specific CMS layout?

Tags: html, css

It's ancient, but there are still some people who use [InsaneJournal](http://www.insanejournal.com) (an offshoot of Danga Interactive's LiveJournal), myself included.

I'm trying to add some very basic content organizers; specifically, CSS-only (InsaneJournal prevents the use of jQuery) tabs and a modal window.  But I *cannot* get them to work.  I've tested the code snippets in JSFiddle, and they work fine (I'll include the snippets below, too), which makes me think there is something in the pre-made layout I'm using which prevents the snippets from working as expected.

Can anyone offer any insight?  The website is [here](http://unbowed.insanejournal.com) and these are the snippets:

Modal Window:

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog>div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover {
  background: #00d9ff;
}
```

```html
<h1><a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a></h1>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div> <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

    <h2>Modal Window</h2>

    <p>This is a modal window.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Tabs:

```css
.tabs {
  color: #333;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 80%;
}

.tabs ul.tab-nav {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.tabs ul.tab-nav li {
  display: table-cell;
}

.tabs ul.tab-nav li a {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.214em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tabs ul.tab-nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tabs section article {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
}

.tabs section:target article {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <h1>CSS-only Tabs (POC)</h1>
  <ul class="tab-nav">
    <li><a href="#option1">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#option2">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#option3">Option 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <section id="option1">
    <article>
      <h2>Heading 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ut lacus vel eros maximus pharetra. Nullam mattis posuere eros, ac pellentesque felis lobortis id. Fusce sed varius mauris. Integer ut pulvinar metus. Vestibulum ?obortis non enim
        quis pulvinar. Maecenas et pulvinar mi. Pellentesque gravida eleifend nisl vitae efficitur. Curabitur sit amet convallis elit, sit amet ultrices enim. Integer vitae erat sit amet mi viverra gravida.</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section id="option2">
    <article>
      <h2>Heading 2</h2>
      <p>Aenean eu mauris sagittis magna fringilla rhoncus. Mauris ornare felis at rutrum condimentum. Fusce in fermentum ipsum. Duis et dignissim orci, at venenatis urna. Etiam condimentum malesuada placerat. In sollicitudin justo fermentum velit facilisis
        aliquam. Duis psuere, neque iaculis dignissim scelerisque, dolor orci vulputate dui, et pulvinar dui ante pharetra ipsum.</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section id="option3">
    <article>
      <h2>Heading 3</h2>
      <p>Duis lectus magna, tristique quis tristique ac, eleifend nec sapien. Quisque vel eros nec tortor efficitur malesuada. Suspendisse malesuada, erat eu posuere finibus, velit tellus placerat mauris, id pharetra nunc velit et nisi. Phasellus non diam
        sapien. Ut tellus est, tristique sit amet arcu eget, egestas porta sapien. Sed maximus, turpis ut tempor imperdiet, sem nisi lobortis enim, vel ultrices elit turpis eu nisi. Morbi efficitur luctus justo, eget ultrices lorem luctus ac. Quisque
        id augue risus. Cras sagittis dapibus sapien vehicula auctor. Nullam iaculis ipsum leo, sed ornare arcu placerat sit amet. Aenean aliquet dictum ligula non rhoncus. Duis lacinia, nisl sed porttitor scelerisque, ex ex viverra massa, sit amet ullamcorper
        sem nulla sit amet urna.</p>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>
```

These are pasted directly from the code I'm using on my blog.  As you can see, they operate (here, in Codepen, in jsFiddle, *everywhere*) as expected.

I do not see why (or what) would prevent these really very simple codes from operating as they ought to.  Can anyone tell me what is going on here?  Or point me in the right direction?  Or even offer a means of circumventing what's going on here?  I'll take any kind of help.

Thank you for your time, and I apologize if this is very simplistic.  I'm not very advanced at all (as if that isn't obvious).

**EDIT** As pointed out by [Mehravish Temkar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6808043/mehravish-temkar), the div ids are not showing up in the page even after they've been entered.  Does anyone know what is removing them from the code?  And, for that matter (and just out of curiosity), why they would be removed?

Comment: I don't see the modal div with id="openModal" on your webpage

Comment: Your sections don't have id either hence they are not working on your wesbite

Comment: And yet when I enter the code into the layout, it is _precisely_ what I'm entering here (with div ids).  I'm assuming (for some reason?) the code is being stripped out, so is there a way of 'forcing' it to acknowledge the ids?

Comment: try to recheck if the code is there, or add it again.

Comment: I've just rechecked, and it's definitely there: https://gyazo.com/bd4e8327d57a5b6b15e70ef93b17d357

Comment: Is there anything like publish code or something for the website? maybe the code is not being updated

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a super-simplistic, 'Save Entry' type of system.  So if the entry is there, the code has been saved.  I'm thinking it's just something in Danga Interactive's antiquated way of doing things that has decided the users shouldn't be able to designate their own ids.  (And, oddly enough, classes seem to work fine.)

Comment: if classes are working fine then use unique class names. You know how to use jquery?

Comment: Still just for trial, try changing a text somewhere in code and see if it is being reflected on the website

Comment: I'd **love** to use jquery here, but unfortunately, it's one I know InsaneJournal strips out for 'security reasons' (apparently).  Thank you so much for your help, though.  I was starting to think I was doing something spectacularly stupid. :P  And yes, I just tried changing 'option 3' and sure enough, it went through.  Since it seems to be only ids that are being dumped, I'm going to take your suggestion and muck about with it a little bit to see what I come up with.  Again, thank you so so much for the time you've taken.

Comment: :P I wish i could have helped. Good luck. Still you can reach out for help here. I hope you get it done.